# How to delete alertDialog.builder in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a sample code to show a pop-up message(alertDialog.butiler) for every 20 seconds which is kept in the scheduler. the problem is a new window pop-up is overwritten on the old pop-up for every 20 sec's, so how can I overcome this, I need to get a single pop-up and if that pop-up is alive the new pop-up window should not be generated. so, please help me.

This is my sample code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


ScheduledFuture<?> s = null;
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = null;
scheduler=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
s=scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new

Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run () {
            System.out.println("Called the scheduler");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (showAlertDialog) {
                        if (!isFinishing()) {
                            System.out.println("Called the scheduler on ui thread");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WaitForRiderAllocationActivity.this);
                            builder.setCancelable(false);
                            builder.setTitle("TRIP UPDATES");
                            builder.setMessage("All are our riders are busy, do you want to still continue?");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Toast.makeText(WaitForRiderAllocationActivity.this, "some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(WaitForRiderAllocationActivity.this, GiveRideTakeRideActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            builder.show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                );
            }
        },
        0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: dismiss the dialog before showing the new one.

Comment: builder.dismiss() is not supporting

Comment: Make the builder object before calling the builder

Comment: sorry i didn't get you ranjan, can you say me clearly

Comment: AlertDialog dialog ;
//for creating dialog instance
dialog = builder.create();

//Dismiss dialog
dialog.dismiss()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the AlertBuilder object global and inside your scheduler check if the builder object is null and create your dialog

```
// Global object
AlertBuilder builder; 


...
    s = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Called the scheduler");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (showAlertDialog){
                    if(!isFinishing()){
                        System.out.println("Called the scheduler on ui thread");
                        if(builder == null){
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WaitForRiderAllocationActivity.this);                         builder.setCancelable(false);
                            builder.setTitle("TRIP UPDATES");
                            builder.setMessage("All are our riders are busy, do you want to still continue?");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Toast.makeText(WaitForRiderAllocationActivity.this,"some text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(WaitForRiderAllocationActivity.this, GiveRideTakeRideActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            builder.show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },
    0, 20,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: HI suresh, the above code is working fine, but when i click on continue button the activity is closing, it should not be closed, it need to ask the pop-up after 20sec's

Comment: HI suresh, if(builder == null) is working fine, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep reference to dialog you have shown:

```
 if(mDialog!=null) {
      mDialog.dismiss();
      mDialog = null;
 }
 . . .
 mDialog = builder.show();
```

Comment: what is mDialog here RadekJ? is it alertDialog object?

Comment: how to initialize mDialog, can you suggest me plz

Comment: you are already doing this in line  where you have: builder.show();, the method .show() returns AlretDialog, you should keep reference to it, then you can check if it is not null and check if it is showing (isShowing()) and dismiss it if you want (dismiss()).

Comment: if(builder == null) is working fine RdekJ, but when i clicks on continue button the activity is closing, but the activity should not be closed it need to get next pop-up after 20 sec's, please help me in this regard

Comment: Thanks RadekJ, if(builder == null) is working fine, thanks for helping.

Comment: you should stop this scheduler if activity is destroyed

Comment: you want this popups even if user leaves your application? If yes you should use Service and Notification